# What I want to do is convert the double value of variable to exponential form only if number has more than 5 zero's after decimal point in java

Tags: java, android

**This is my function to convert input values ->**

```
private void frequencyUnitConverter(Utils.FrequencyUnit from, Utils.FrequencyUnit to, double input) {
        double constant = 1;
        switch (from) {
            case HERTZ:
                if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.KILOHERTZ) {
                    constant = 0.001;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.MEGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e-6;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.GIGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e-9;
                }
                break;
            case KILOHERTZ:
                if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.HERTZ) {
                    constant = 1000;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.MEGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 0.001;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.GIGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e-6;
                }
                break;
            case MEGAHERTZ:
                if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.HERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e+6;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.KILOHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1000;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.GIGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 0.001;
                }
                break;
            case GIGAHERTZ:
                if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.HERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e+9;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.KILOHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1e+6;
                } else if (to == Utils.FrequencyUnit.MEGAHERTZ) {
                    constant = 1000;
                }
                break;
        }

        double result = input * constant;
        binding.outputNumText.setText(String.valueOf(result).toLowerCase());
    }
```

**Currently I get something like this ->**

[image]

***Here result should be 0.000123 format instead of 1.2299999999999998e-4 format.**

After calculating result with* `double result = input * constant;` *How can I convert it to exponential format only and only if it has 5 zero's after decimal point otherwise print result in simple decimal format. e.g. 0.000123*

Comment: ok? what is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: Here 123 hertz is input and 1.2299999999999998e-4 is converted value of hertz to megahertz which can be shown as 0.000123 which I want. So, what I want is my resultant value should be converted to exponent form only if it has e-6 i.e 5 zeros after decimal point else it should be displayed in decimal form like 0.000123 in this example

Comment: all you put is what you have and what you want, but not what actual problem you are having. what have you tried, what is it that's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not going to convert this number but to display this number you can do below,

```
double noExpo = 1.2299999999999998e-4;

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
Log.e("number", ":::" + formatter.format(noExpo));
```

output -->

number: 0.000123

Comment: Doesn't seems to work for me. Can you tell me how exactly I should implement your logic?

Comment: can you tell me what issue you are facing after adding this code?@Akash